# Angular2 Ionic2 Can't resolve all parameters for GameServiceProvider: (?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
Runtime Error
Can't resolve all parameters for GameServiceProvider: (?).

Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GameServiceProvider: (?).
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:78899:34)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92236:35)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92104:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92090:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92380:40)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92309:49
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92270:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91700:30)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92357:45)
```

I have two providers bot and game-service
This is my game-service provider inside providers/games-service/game-service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BotProvider } from '../bot/bot';
@Component({
  providers: [BotProvider]
})
 @Injectable()
export class GameServiceProvider {
 ... vars i have to use some in Botprovider aswell ...
 constructor(public bot: BotProvider){
 }
 ... functions ...
}
```

this is my bot provider inside providers/bot/bot.ts

```js
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GameServiceProvider } from '../game-service/game-service';
@Component({
  providers: [GameServiceProvider]
})
@Injectable()
export class BotProvider {
 constructor(public gs: GameServiceProvider) {}
 .. functions ..
}
```

Both where created via `ionic generate provider {{NAME}}`

My app.compoment.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { BotProvider } from '../providers/bot/bot';
import { GameServiceProvider } from '../providers/game-service/game-service';


import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [GameServiceProvider,BotProvider]
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

My app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { GamePage } from '../pages/game/game';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { BotProvider } from '../providers/bot/bot';
import { GameServiceProvider } from '../providers/game-service/game-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    GamePage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    MaterialModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    GamePage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    GooglePlus,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    BotProvider,
    GameServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Should i write another Provider that contains just the stuff both Provider need or is it possible that one provider has a provider in its constructor and vise versa
**Have a nice weekend!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one references to `GameServiceProvider` viz.,

- **AppModule**
- **BotProvider**
- **MyApp**

Remove the providers block in each files and have it globally in the `AppModule`