# Angular 2/ Typescript Re-export: "Module not found: Can't resolve [...]"

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I'm working with Angular 2 and Typescript. I'm trying to create a collection of classes, each defined in its own file, and want to be able to import them with a single (or perhaps) more lines.

Something similar like this:

```
// lib/foo.ts
export class Foo {}

// lib/bar.ts
export class Bar {}

// lib/index.d.ts
export * from './foo';
export * from './bar';

// app.component.ts
import * as lib from './lib';

...
let foo = new lib.Foo();
let bar = new lib.Bar();
```

I searched a while through the internet, and tried a lot of possible ways in my code, but none of them seems to work. For example, in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557587/re-exporting-es6-modules-in-ts-1-7), it seems to be the same syntax as mine (the code just above).

So maybe this is an angular specific issue?

Here's the full error message I receive, when building with "ng serve" (on the angular cli):

```
ERROR in ./src/app/api-module/services/factory.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../sketch-objects' in 'D:\[...]\PhpStorm\vector-sketch\src\app\api-module\services'
 @ ./src/app/api-module/services/factory.service.ts 8:0-51
```

While having an import like the following works:

```
import {Scene} from '../sketch-objects/scene';
```

Just for understanding: I am programming an app which deals with threeJS, and want to create some sort of factory, which builds threeJS objects (or more precisely, a wrapper around a threeJS object) according to a specific string given in. For example I have a function

```
// factory.service.ts
import * as lib from './lib'

...
create(objectType: string): any {

  let threeObject = lib[objectType]();
  return threeObject;
}
```

I appreciate any help, Thanks. 
bertiooo

Comment: what is the use of having `import * as lib from './lib'`

Comment: As stated here: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-the-entire-module-into-a-single-variable-and-use-it-to-access-the-module-exports), one can import an entire module into a single variable and use it to access the module exports

Comment: Ok, you pointed me in the right direction. I thought the module loader would automatically look for an index.d.ts when writing just `'./lib'`, but obviously hasn't found anything. Now I wrote `./lib/index` and that worked! Thank you!

Comment: so was my answer helpful?? or need more help?

Comment: Yes! You were helpful. Thank you very much. Don't need more help.

Comment: Thank you. :) Happy coding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing single service from two places which creates two instances

1. See this line

   ```
   import {Scene} from '../sketch-objects/scene';
   ```
2. Second import from the lib file

   ```
   import * as lib from './lib'
   ```

   So angular will not know which service instance to pick when the Sketch service is used.

**To solve this, import services from the same path**

**Note:** **[Also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996095/angular2-ionic2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-gameserviceprovider/44996310#44996310)**